# rss and json php scripts pulling data from mysql

Tags: php, json, xml, rss

I have an sql database with data and would like to create 2 php scripts to output data in rss format and json format but I am stuck because there is something wrong with the code... I think. I also want to be globally recognized as rss and json formats respectively. Here are the two sets of code that I have already...

For rss/xml...

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
/* Define db credentials */ 
    $DBHOST = "localhost";
    $DBUSER = "1";
    $DBPASS = "2";
    $DBNAME = "3";
    $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
    $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>RSS Feed</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.123.net</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>RSS Feed</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
    $rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2018 123.net</copyright>';
/* connect to the db */
   $conn = new mysqli($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $DBNAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) { trigger_error('Database connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR); }
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 5";
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if ($rs === false) { trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR); } else { $row_num = $rs->num_rows; }
$rssfeed .= '<item>';
        $rssfeed .= '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
        $rssfeed .= '<desc>' . $desc . '</desc>';
$rssfeed .= '</item>';
    } 
    $rssfeed .= '</channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '</rss>';
    echo $rssfeed;
```

For json...

```
<?php
/* Define db credentials */ 
    $DBHOST = "localhost";
    $DBUSER = "1";
    $DBPASS = "2";
    $DBNAME = "3";
/* connect to the db */
   $conn = new mysqli($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $DBNAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) { trigger_error('Database connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR); }
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    $query= "Select * from table ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract($row);
    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: In your json script you are mixing `mysqli_*`with `mysql_*`. Replace the `mysql_*` calls. And why are you extracting arrays instead of adding the items to `$array`? And in the first script you are not even fetching rows. A bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code:

```
$jsonResult = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $jsonResult[] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($jsonResult);
```

Comment: Why would you advocate mixing two APIs? Especially since one of them is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) in the newer versions of PHP.

Comment: look what @jeroen said in the comments in the question!

Comment: I am trying this  
    $query= "Select * from table ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 5";
 $result = mysqli_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");
$jsonResult = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $jsonResult[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($jsonResult);
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($conn);
?>  and I get a "Could not execute query"!

Comment: also with mysqli_free_result($result); mysqli_close($conn) I get the same error

Comment: I found the problem. I was using $result = mysqli_query($query) instead of $result = mysqli_query($con, $query). I forgot the "$con"